# Setting timer after an asynchronous call returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an asynchronous Ajax function which runs a command string at the server side and returns the result to the client. It calls a callback to process the result.

```
function ajaxCall(commandStr,callback){
   var url=......//make a url with the command string
   jquery.get(url,function(result){
       //process the result using callback
       callback(result);
   });
}
```

The asynchronous call (ajaxCall) may take a while to be finished but I want it to do the same command after an interval (1000ms).

I want to write a function that is like this:

```
function ajaxCallRepeated(interval,commandStr,callback)
```

I tried closures like this:

```
function ajaxCallRepeated(interval,commandStr,callback){
    //This feature uses closures in Javascript. Please read this to know why and how: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clSto
    function callLater(param1,param2,param3){
        return (function(){
            ajaxCall(param2,function(out,err){
                if(param3)param3(out,err);
                var functRef = callLater(param1,param2,param3);
                setTimeout(functRef, interval);
            });
        });
    }
    //the first call
    var functRef = callLater(interval,commandStr,callback);
    setTimeout(functRef, interval);
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
ajaxCallRepeated(2000,"ls",function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

But it only runs the command 2 times.
How can I write a function that will reschedule itself after it is called as a callback of an asynchronous function?

PS. I want to fire another Ajax call after the previous one is finished. Also, it worth to mention that axashCallRepeated() will be called with various parameters, so several Ajax calls are running in parallel, but for each commandStr, there is only one Ajax call going on, and after the Ajax call returns, another one will be fired after X seconds.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to schedule new ajax call with your callback to fire every X seconds, **regardless** of the fact that previous ajax call may not be finished yet, or do you want to fire ajax calls in sequence (fire another after previous one is finished)?

Comment: I want to fire another Ajax call after the previous one is finished. Also, it worth to mention that axashCallRepeated() will be called with various parameters, so several Ajax calls are running in parallel, but for each commandStr, there is only one Ajax call going on, and after the Ajax call returns, another one will be fired after X seconds.

Comment: I would trigger a custom Event when the first Ajax call is finished and then second one will be executed !

Answer (score 1):

I would not use setTimeout to trigger the second Ajax call ! Because you never know how long it will take and if it's finished !
 As far as you tagged your question right and you ARE using jquery you should consider something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(){
    // The AJAX is successfully done, now you trigger your custom event:
    $(document).trigger('myAjaxHasCompleted');
  },
  dataType: dataType
});

$(function(){
    //somehwere in your document ready block
    $(document).on("myAjaxHasCompleted",function(){
        $.ajax({
            //execute the second one
        });
    });
});
```

So this would ensure that the ajax post is DONE and was successful and now you could execute the second one. I know its not the exact answer to your question but you should consider on using something like this ! Would make it safer I guess :-)

Comment: Good idea, but you may need to pass additional data to your custom event (like command in our example) to know command with which ajax call has been completed.

Comment: I agree ! But my answer should be considered as a hint to the way it could be done so, I think he will recognize this :-)

Comment: Yeah I recently came over this way by custom events ! I was also using setTimeout in certain projects to ensure that my ajax calls were done but, thats no secure way and no clean solution so it shouldn't be done because there are better ways to do this :)

Comment: @EvilP: interesting idea. I didn't know about $(document).trigger() but as WTK said I have some parameters to pass to that function. However it seems it is possible to pass parameters to trigger() as well: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ I came up with a solution that I'll write as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this problem is to save a reference to the closure itself and use it when scheduling the next call:

```
function ajaxCallRepeated(interval,commandStr,callback){
    //This feature uses closures in Javascript. Please read this to know why and how: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clSto
    function callLater(_interval,_commandString,_callback){
        var closure=(function(){
            ajaxCall(_commandString,function(out,err){
                if(_callback)_callback(out,err);
                setTimeout(closure,_interval);
            });
        });
        return closure;
    }
    //now make a closure for every call to this function
    var functRef = callLater(interval,commandString,callback);
    //the first call
    functRef();
}
```

Comment: If you're satisfied with your own answer please remember to accept it, so your question doesn't list as "unaswered". Thanks!

Comment: I tried, but it says I can't accept my own answer till 2 days after asking the question. It helps to vote it up so that it goes up and people see that there is a good answer to it though. I can't vote up my own answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes easier to reason about if you separate things up a bit.

For example, the repetition logic doesn't have to know about AJAX or callbacks at all:

```
function mkRepeater(interval, fn, fnScope, fnArgs) {
  var running;

  function repeat() {
    if (!running) return;
    fn.apply(fnScope, fnArgs);
    setTimeout(repeat, interval);
  }

  return {
   start: function() { running = true; repeat(); },
   stop: function() { running = false; }
  };
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var r = mkRepeater(2000, ajaxFunction, this, ["getStuff", callbackFn]);
r.start();
...
r.stop();
```

Comment: repeat() uses the same values for interval, fn, fnScope, fnArgs every time mkRepeater() is called. I need to run several calls in parallel.

Comment: You need to call several *different* calls, but you need to stagger them?